# Matching verb tenses when starting a sentence with "this"

Tags: verbs, tenses

The phrase in question is

"This allows his arms to naturally accelerate through the bottom of his swing and unleashes a lot of power on the ball."

My question is about the proper tense of the verb, "unleashes". I'm unsure if it's supposed to match the verb "allows", as in "this allows... this unleashes", or the verb "accelerate", as in "his arms accelerate... his arms unleash".

Either way illustrates the point I'm trying to make.

I suppose the verb tenses are clear if the sentence didn't start with "This". It could be rewritten as "His arms accelerate... and unleash...".

I wanted to start this sentence with "This" to refer to the point I made in the sentence before.

Comment: You can parse it both ways. It could be "This allows his arms to naturally accelerate through the bottom of his swing and to unleash a lot of power on the ball", with the "to" elided. Or "unleashes" could go with the "this" at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: and both ways are "correct"?

Comment: Both ways are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the subject to which the verb rightfully belongs - if it's the arms, then they unleash. If it's whatever you talked about in the previous sentence, then it (aka 'this') unleashes.

Comment: So I understand that the different tenses point to different subjects, but are you saying both ways are grammatically "correct"?

Comment: @parker.sikand - the differences in the verbs are not in tense (they're both in the simple present), they're to do with agreement either with a plural subject 'the arms' in the third person plural, or a singular subject 'it' in the third person singular.